# How to check from the command line if a java SSL certificate really works in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I wrote a small bash script that does import a SSL certificate in Java keystore but I do want to add some code that would also verify that Java can establish a connection using this certifiate (in some cased is can be expired,...).

The bash script is located at https://gist.github.com/3164098 and I am looking for a solution that would test this without having to add another .java file, still downloding an already compiled testing class from net would be considered a valid alternative.

Comment: These [previous stackoverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4517532/390462) will give you the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code snippet:

```
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path_to_your_truststore");          
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");                 


HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("URL").openConnection();  

connection.setDoInput(true);                                                         
connection.setDoOutput(true);                                                        
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");                                                  

connection.connect();
```